# Browser back button asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, back-button

I am implementing a web based system. I need to capture if the back button of browser is pressed. It doesnt postback if the back button is pressed. I have seen some code parts but it doesnt solve my problem. I have a home page. I want to postback my homepage if the back button of browser is clicked.

Well to be more clear-> Home page-> x.aspx?Date=30.01.2012 , I put the date to the session, then the back button of browser,Home page ????  There I want to get the date from the session by postbacking the home page.

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible...

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy problem to solve for a few reasons:

- Caching behaves differently on different browsers
- You are going to be interfering with natural UI interaction which is ill advised
- It's probably a design problem

I wouldn't attempt this for those reasons, and would instead look at the problem from a different angle (for example, is it a design problem?)

For what it's worth I think this is possible to a certain level but it would be an overly complex solution for the task it's trying to solve and very difficult to debug/maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to avoid the case where a user goes back and resubmits a form. You can avoid having to detect the use of the back button by using the [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (PRG) pattern instead. After handling the form submission, do a redirect to the page you would like to be on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) with the `EnableHistory` property set to true.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
    EnableHistory="true" />
```

An article on MSDN describing this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc488548.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable back button on one of the page try using below javascript

function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }

&  in your body tag write below

<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">

This should surely solve your problem.

Happy Coding !!